# SGS4 android 4.4.2 - OGL ES2 crashes

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crash, opengl-es-2.0

Here i have one application published at Google Play. There was no ANR/Crashes since publication at over 400 installs.
 But at this week i found 3 new crashes. All 3 was on same device, same android version. All 3 crashes are totally same.

Device is : Samsung Galaxy S4 (jfltevzw). Here is crash report.

```
Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/jfltevzw/jfltevzw:4.4.2/KOT49H/I545VRUFNC5:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 8444, tid: 8457, name: ###.game### >>> com.###.game### <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000006c
r0 76d47a96 r1 76d47a94 r2 0000006c r3 00000006
r4 00000006 r5 0000006c r6 79a14818 r7 0000006c
r8 79a14008 r9 00000001 sl 0000006c fp 00000000
ip 00000000 sp 76d47a38 lr 7608a95f pc 7608a282 cpsr 60070030
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 000000000f000008 d5 00000000ffff0400
d6 0000000044220000 d7 0000000000000000
d8 3ea0000000000000 d9 3fe0000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 3f8000003f800000 d17 3a020ce03f800000
d18 3acccccd00000000 d19 0000000000000000
d20 0000000000000000 d21 000000003a032338
d22 3c5999c0bab60c00 d23 3f8000003e064324
d24 0000000000000000 d25 0000000000000000
d26 0000000000000000 d27 0000000000000000
d28 3fef8d75f3bcb1e2 d29 bfdffffffd0c5e81
d30 0000000000000000 d31 0000000000000000
scr 60000017

backtrace:
#00 pc 00046282 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (neon_pld_min_max_16+5)
#01 pc 0004695b /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (cache_vertex_elements+80)
#02 pc 00049e61 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (core_glDrawElementsInstancedXXX+328)
#03 pc 00049fd7 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (core_glDrawElements+10)
#04 pc 00039767 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glDrawElements+28)
#05 pc 000e72b1 ###
#06 pc 000d9567 ###
#07 pc 000bd857 ###
```

Application uses OpenGL ES2.0, VBO and IBO used intensively.

I know that the problem lies between bound index buffer and called glDrawElements with index buffer offset (not the pointer) in last arg.

**fault addr 0000006c** ( and **r7 0000006c** ) is an offset to first index inside IBO.
IBO object contains more than 2000 items and such crash can not be caused by invalid IBO.

I can't understand why crashes appears only at SGS4. Can somebody help me to understand this situation?

**UPD:**
I use my own crossplatform c++ engine, which drives games on win/mac/nix/ios/android/bada devices. The problem with OGL IBO and Adreno GPU appears only on SGS4 model.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Note if anybody wants to reach out to unity, you can also reference https://unity3d.zendesk.com/requests/14018.

They have narrowed this issue down based on our project but there is no solution yet. I'm sure they would welcome more source code for testing and regressing though.

Answer (score 0):

Referred from

http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/application-crashes-on-android-adreno-based-graphics-drivers

There is a walking around by adding

```
void OnGUI(){ 
GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,1,1), ""); 
}
```

to each scene.